# JBOSS EAP 6.4 dependency

Tags: jboss6.x

We are deploying multiple Maven application wars in Jboss EAP 6.4. All Maven applications have some common jars. We want to put the common  dependencies in Jboss server.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom module. http://michaelrice.com/2015/01/how-to-develop-a-custom-module-for-jboss-eap-6x-as-7
And then set the dependencies in a file (WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml) in each WAR you will deploy.

If you have JBoss EAP subscription you can get more complete documentation: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/195403

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the list of custom jar and jar which already exists in Jboss EAP6 as this can cause issue while deploying because of multiple jars

Next Create a deployment structure then set the dependencies in a file (WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml) (Add this to your multiple project )

Make sure to exclude dependencies causing multiples by defining in the above file.

check if you need any submodule in config files of JBOSS EAP (you can comment it, if you are not using).

Deploy your project and check if any dependencies causing issue and update it accordingly.